# Configuring Sudo to use AD/LDAP password

Tags: linux, sudo, pam, sssd

Looking into the feasibility of configuring our VMs (RHEL 8) so users in the wheel group use their LDAP password to authenticate for Sudo

What I've done so far is configured sssd for LDAP authentication, and added this to sudoers:
`Defaults !targetpw`

This does get the intended functionality but unfortunately it also allows *any* LDAP user to log in to the VM (we use CA signed ssh certs).
I only want to allow users with a local account.

I've been able to block non-local users by configuring `/etc/pam.d/sshd` to require a local user with `session required pam_localuser.so` at the top.

Is there a better/simpler way to accomplish this?

As requested, a sample of my sssd.conf (copiedanually via my phone because I can't log in to stack exchange from work, so please ignore spelling mistakes or random capitalization):

```
[sssd]
services = nss, pam
config_file_version = 2
domains = MYDOMAIN.LOCAL

[domain/MYDOMAIN.LOCAL]
id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
ldap_schema = ad
ldap_user_name = sAMAccountName
ldap_id_mapping = True
ldap_uri = ldaps://ldaps.example.com:636
ldap_search_base = OU=x,OU=y,DC=MY DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL
ldap_default_bind_dn = CN=service_user,OU=x,OU=y,DC=MY DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL
ldap_default_authtok_type = obfuscated_password
ldap_default_authtok = redacted
ldap_tls_cacert = /path/to/cacert
ldap_id_use_start_tls = True
cache_credentials = True
enumerate = True
ldap_user_object_class = user
ldap_group_name = sAMAccountName
ldap_user_object_class = user
ldap_group_object_class = group
access_provider = permit
sudo_provider = ldap
chpass_provider = ldap
autofs_provider = ldap
resolver_provider = ldap
```

Comment: `pam_localuser` could work, as could `pam_wheel`

Comment: Can I please also get you to clarify: in the first paragraph you're talking about using `wheel` group to permit LDAP authentication for `sudo`, with an implication that other users can log on to the system. A bit later on though, in the third paragraph, you seem to suggest you're wanting to prevent any (non-`wheel`?) LDAP user from logging in at all. Which problem are you trying to resolve?

Comment: I want to allow non-wheel to log in but not execute Sudo. The problem is AD users are able to ssh right now without even having a local account on the VM. It's a strange result where they have no home dir and a really large uid and gid.

Comment: (1) Why are you using LDAP instead of AD if it's an AD-based organisation? You can use `sssd-ad` instead of `sssd-ldap`

Comment: (2) You say, "_It's a strange result where they have no home dir_" - if you use `pam_mkhomedir` they can get home directories automatically when they log in

Comment: (3) Modify the PAM configuration for `sudo` to disallow non-wheel users. Depending on your use case you might want to use `pam_localuser` or more likely `pam_wheel`

Comment: 1. I don't have an answer there. I'll look into sssd-ad

Comment: 2. I don't want any user to be able to ssh to any VM, only users who have an account on that VM so having pam make the home directory it kind of the opposite of what I'm after

Comment: 3. Sudo already disallows users who are not in wheel l, presumably from the initial redhat configuration so I don't think I need to add anything there, unless pam can be used to specify the password should come from ad/ldap

Comment: (2) "_I don't want any user to be able to ssh to any VM_" isn't what you've said anywhere in your question. What you have said is that you only want users with a local account to be able to use `sudo`. That's completely different. Please [edit] your question to make your requirement quite clear.

Comment: Oh I see. You want to allow only users with a local account to be able to log in to the VM. But you then want them to use their AD password to authenticate to AD. That wasn't clear until your comments just now. What about creating an AD group and using membership of that to determine whether or not a user can login. That's how `sssd-ad` works out of the box, so you're not having to invent anything unusual. All authentication then uses AD account and password, whether for login or `sudo`

Comment: That's sounding like I'd be iterating towards redhat idm, which I'd be fine with but we already have a system in place to manage user accounts based on user groups, spanning >1000 hosts not all of which fall under me. I guess I'm just finding this behaviour of allowing 'anonymous' login very bizarre, to the point it makes me think something is configured wrong. It might be that it's just uncommon for places to use CA signed SSH certs so this area isnt well known

Comment: You've set up sssd without any restriction on who has an account (i.e. group-based restrictions), so therefore because everyone in your AD has an account, everyone can log in

Comment: It's starting to feel like sssd is the problem honestly. It feels a bit like I'm using an Apache to cross the street.

Comment: sssd does the equivalent of adding your entire AD population on to the end of /etc/passwd. If you want to filter that set of users you need a mechanism to do so and the usual one is group membership. (That group membership could, I think, be managed inside /etc/group if you can't do it in AD, but that's not very devolved.)

Comment: I appreciate your help on this. Not sure what I'll do yet though